# JqGrid with datatype:local and Ajax local data for grid Load

Tags: ajax, jqgrid

I need solutions for the following in JQGRID  with Following only

a) datatype : "local"  data is local only  **[ cannot use datatype : json ]**

b) Grid Table Data is independent of the Column headers [ cannot hardcode column names within the table data ]

c)Need to load Grid data via Ajax into the Grid page (via url)

with regards
karthik

Comment: Could you be more exactly? If the format of data is fixed then you can include an example of the data. What you tried before? Could you includes the code? All what you wrote can be easy implemented, but it's absolutely unclear **in which parts of implementation you have some problems**. You wrote "Need to load Grid data via Ajax". OK then why you don't use `datatype : "json"` with optional `loadonce: true`? One can make separate `jQuery.ajax` request (but it's unclear why) and use `datatype: "local", data: dataReturnedFromTheServer`. Where you have a problem? **Which format have the data?**

Comment: I cannot use "datatype:json"  for somne other reason.

Comment: Could you answer on other my questions. By the way probably you misunderstand how `datatype:"json"` work. You wrote that you 'cannot use "datatype:json"', but you wrote "Need to load Grid data via Ajax". jqGrid makes Ajax call internally if `datatype:"json"` are used. You have *many options* which allows you full customize the Ajax call which will be sent by jqGrid. **So you should describe details of your problem**.

Comment: I know that "Datatype:json" using Ajax  is an easy approach , but with restrictions on using json from the relevant concern ...i cannot convince the same... So i am forced to use "datatype: local"   The data feed can be either from an RDBMS AND from a  local CSV file  for comparison purpose.